# How do I get a dropdown choice to show up on the left of an entry on this To-Do list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

thank you for looking. Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/mlynn/pen/WbLEeR

I'm trying to allow the user to select a number from the dropdown list, and type in a word in the "To Do" input box, and when they hit enter, they will see an entry with their "To-Do" text in the middle and the # they chose on the left of the entry.

How can this be achieved? I'm not very good at Javascript and have mostly been tinkering with premade codepens, desperately trying to put pieces together.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--

-->
<html lang="en">
    <head>               
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styletime.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>      
    </head>


    <body>
        <section id="heady">
            <div style="text-align: left;padding:25px 70px;display:inline-block;float:left;"><b><a href="index.html">Site</b></a></p></div>

            <div style="text-align: right;padding:25px 70px;display:inline-block;float:right;">    
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a> | 
                    <a href="index.html">Generic</a> |
                    <a href="index.html">Elements</a> |
                    <a href="index.html">Sign Up</a>
            </div>


        </section>

        <section id="wrapper">
            <br><br>
            <img src="images/blacksquare.png" width="525" height="197"></img>

            <br><br><br>


            <div>
                <div style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;float:left;">        
                    <ul class="navbar cf">
                        <!-- <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li> -->
                        <li style="width:200px;">
                            <a href="#" class="ActiveListItem">#</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>                                                               


                <div class="container lister" style="display:inline-block;float:left;vertical-align:top;padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
                    <form action="">
                        <input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Enter a To-do and hit enter">
                    </form>
                    <br>

                    <!-- <ul class="active">
                        <li>Work <a href="">X</a></li>
                        <li>Sleep <a href="">X</a></li>
                        <li>Repeat <a href="">X</a></li>
                    </ul> -->

                </div>



                <div class="container lister" style="display:inline-block;float:left;vertical-align:top;padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
                    <ul class="active">
                        <li>Work <a href="">X</a></li>
                        <li>Sleep <a href="">X</a></li>
                        <li>Repeat <a href="">X</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>     
        </section>



        <section id="feety">
        I believe I exist
        </section>         




    </body>


</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*adder*/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400, 300, 600);


 * {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


html {
 background:teal;
}


body {
    /*background:url('https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/4657039731.jpg');*/
}


a {
    color: #D9D9D9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active, a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}



#heady {
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    height:75px;
    background-color:#222;                       /*Back Colors*/
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:white;
    position:relative; 
}

#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:teal;                       /*Back Colors*/
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    position:relative; 
}


#feety {
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:darkslateblue;                       /*Back Colors*/
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:white;
    position:relative; 
}










/* clearfix */
/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cf {
   * zoom: 1;
}


ul.navbar {

  background:white; 
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:gray;
  border-width:1px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 4px;

}


.ActiveListItem:after {
    content: "\25BC\00a0\00a0";                        /*carat and spaces*/
    float:right;
    font-weight:900;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    font-size:100%; 
    line-height:20px;             /*keeps carat in center of text*/
}




ul.navbar li a.ActiveListItem {
    background:white !important;
    color:black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:white;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding:3px 5px !important;
    font-weight:normal !important;
    margin-left:14px;/* got the activeitem centered with the list text this way*/
    margin-right:0px;

}

ul.navbar li {
    position: relative;
}

ul.navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding:10px 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;

}

ul.navbar li a:hover,
ul.navbar li:hover > a {
    background:#a6d0e1; /*Leaving for now, but keep in mind things bold slowly when you change this to gradient*/
    color: #333;
    font-weight:900;

}

    ul.navbar li ul {
        margin-top: 1px;
        position: absolute;
        background: #222;
        font-size: 14px;
        min-width: 200px;
        display: none;
        z-index: 99;
        box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.6),
        0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    }

ol, ul { list-style: outside none none; }

.hidden { display: none; }







/*Lister*/



.container {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

form {  }

input,
ul {
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:"Tahoma";
}

input {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.lister ul {
    list-style: square inside;
    padding: 10px;
}

.active { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

.inactive { display: none; }

.lister li {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #34495e;
}

.lister li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #dadfe1;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.lister li > a {
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #22313f;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.lister li > a:hover {
    font-size: 110%;
    color: #c0392b;
}


.lister li:before {
    content: "#";                        /*carat and spaces*/
    float:left;
    font-weight:900;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    font-size:100%; 
    line-height:20px;             /*keeps carat in center of text*/
}
```

JS:

```
// sub menus identification
$(function() {
  $('.navbar ul li a').click(function(){  
    $('.navbar > li:first-child > a').text($(this).text());
    $('.navbar > li > ul').addClass('hidden');
    $('.navbar li ul').slideToggle(100);
  });
  $('.navbar > li').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').removeClass('hidden');
  });
  $('.ActiveListItem').click(function(){        
    $('.navbar li ul').slideToggle(300);
  });    
});









//newList

$(document).ready(function() {  

    var ul = $('.lister ul'),
        input = $('input');

    input.focus();  

    $('form').submit(function () {
        if (input.val() !== '') {
            var inputVal = input.val();
            ul.append('<li>' + inputVal + '<a href="">X</a></li>');
            if (ul.hasClass('inactive')) {
                ul.removeClass('inactive')
                    .addClass('active');
            }
        };
        input.val('');
        return false;
    });

    ul.on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();

        if (ul.children().length == 0) {
            ul.removeClass('active')
                .addClass('inactive');
            input.focus();  
        }
    });

});
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can run it at https://jsfiddle.net/ and put the link in your question.

Comment: I'll do that next time, good to know =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated a part of your code in the form submit event handler:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
        if (input.val() !== '') {
            var inputVal = input.val(),
                activeNumber = $('.ActiveListItem').text(); // gets the selected number

            // adds the selected number on before the inputValue:
            ul.append('<li>' + activeNumber + ' ' +inputVal + '<a href="">X</a></li>');
            if (ul.hasClass('inactive')) {
                ul.removeClass('inactive')
                    .addClass('active');
            }
        };
        input.val('');
        return false;
    });
```

I have placed your sample here: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/531yx3jg/)